# How to know an appointment item is an all day event or not through the outlook add-in (by using office-js)

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

when developing outlook add-in , is there way to know appointment item is an ***all day event*** or not by using office js api such as

```
var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
var isEvent = item.allDayEvent; ???
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EWS for accessing properties not listed in the Office.js. You can use the `mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync` method to make an EWS request to the Exchange server that hosts the user's mailbox.

EWS supports different operations on an Exchange server; for example, item-level operations to copy, find, update, or send an item, and folder-level operations to create, get, or update a folder. But you are interested in the [GetItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getitem-operation) operation. To perform an EWS operation, create an XML SOAP request for that operation. When the operation finishes, you get an XML SOAP response that contains data that is relevant to the operation. EWS SOAP requests and responses follow the schema defined in the Messages.xsd file. Like other EWS schema files, the Message.xsd file is located in the IIS virtual directory that hosts EWS.

To use the `makeEwsRequestAsync` method to initiate an EWS operation, provide the following:

- The XML for the SOAP request for that EWS operation, as an argument to the data parameter
- A callback method (as the callback argument)
- Any optional input data for that callback method (as the userContext argument)

When the EWS SOAP request is complete, Outlook calls the callback method with one argument, which is an AsyncResult object. The callback method can access two properties of the AsyncResult object: the value property, which contains the XML SOAP response of the EWS operation, and optionally, the asyncContext property, which contains any data passed as the userContext parameter. Typically, the callback method then parses the XML in the SOAP response to get any relevant information, and processes that information accordingly.

You can use these operations to get and set many properties of a specified item. This method is available to Outlook add-ins regardless of whether the add-in has been activated in a read or compose form, as long as you specify the ReadWriteMailbox permission in the add-in manifest.

For more information about using makeEwsRequestAsync to access EWS operations, see [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services).

Outlook REST APIs are also available through the Microsoft Graph endpoint but there are some key differences, including how your add-in gets an access token. For more information, see [Outlook REST API via Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/index#outlook-rest-api-via-microsoft-graph).